# Does #pragma warning supported in LLVM for ARM?

Tags: c, llvm-clang

Currently I'm using #pragma warning in my code for #pragma push() and #pragma pop() like below. And code is building success when i use Visual Studio compiler.

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4200) // zero-sized array
#pragma pack (push, 1)
...
...
#pragma pack (pop)
#pragma warning(pop)
```

But when I try to build the same code for LLVM compiler it is showing build error for 
    #pragma warning

How to handle this for building in LLVM without removing it?

Any pointer is encouraging..

Comment: Pragmas are *compiler-specific* directives.

Comment: It's probably done by the frontend, so the destination architecture should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Clang uses a different syntax for warnings:

```
#pragma clang warning "I'm a warning"
```

You can disable the unknow-pragmas warning before emitting the pragma; something like

```
#if defined(__has_warning)
#  if __has_warning("-Wunknown-pragmas")
#    pragma clang diagnostic push
#    pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
...
#    pragma clang diagnostic pop
#  endif
#endif
```

It would be smarter to actually test for MSVC, though, and only write the pragma there…

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable: 4200) // zero-sized array
#  pragma pack (push, 1)
#endif /* defined(_MSC_VER) */
...
...
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  pragma pack (pop)
#  pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

Of course, clang also has a warning for zero-length arrays, as well as pragmas for pushing/popping the error stack, so you might want to include those, too…

```
#if defined(__clang__) && defined(__has_warning)
#  if __has_warning("-Wzero-length-array")
#    pragma clang diagnostic push
#    pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wzero-length-array"
#  endif
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#  pragma warning(push)
#  pragma warning(disable: 4200)
#  pragma pack (push, 1)
#endif
// ...
#if defined(__clang__) && defined(__has_warning)
#  if __has_warning("-Wzero-length-array")
#    pragma clang diagnostic pop
#    pragma clang warning "pop"
#  endif
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#  pragma pack (pop)
#  pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

FWIW, pushing/popping warnings is only available in MSVC 15+; I'm too lazy to check on when that specific warning is supported, but you may want to test for the MSVC version if you want to support older compilers.

Other compilers may or may not support 0-length arrays at all, and if they do they may or may not emit a warning which can be disabled.  The ones I can test conveniently:

- Doesn't support 0-length arrays:

  - suncc
  - pgcc (PGC-S-0047)
- Supports 0-length arrays, doesn't emit a warning

  - TI cl6x
  - ICC
- Supports 0-length arrays and emits a warning in some cases

  - GCC (-Wpedantic)

Other compilers probably support a similar warning, and many support pushing/popping and disabling warnings about unknown pragmas.